# MacBook Pro El Capitan runs out of space on boot

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, ssd

MacBook Pro (10.11.6) All updates. 512Gb SSD with 17Gb free. On Boot, some sort of caching or other process runs that takes free space down to a few megabytes - or even zero. Quickly recovers back to 17Gb free, but only after the various errors appear. Not loading any major programs on boot - just Pathfinder, Google Drive. Don't recall having this problem prior to El Capitan.

Comment: 17Gb is not enough free space. You should clean up cache files, iOS device backups, iOS software updates, etc. This page on [freeing up disk space](http://osxdaily.com/2012/11/11/tips-free-up-disk-space-mac-os-x/) may help you locate the big files. I use the app [OmniDiskSweeper](https://www.omnigroup.com/more/) to find the largest files. (Disclaimer - I'm a user of OmniDiskSweeper and have no financial stake in OmniGroup.)

Comment: Besides 10%-15% space (50 - 75 GB) should remain free on a boot volume what's your question?

Comment: As I said, this seems to be a new behavior as of a very recent OS X update - I've been running with ~15 GB Free for years without a problem, wondering if anyone had specific knowledge of a change in the indexing method or whatever else might be causing this.